# generating occupancy grid maps from open source maps

Tags: mapping, ros, robotics

I want to know is it possible to write a program that  generates a 2d occupancy grid map from an open source map such as "Openstreetmap" in order to use it with robot localization ..

Will the information that can be extracted from such maps will be enough to know if this is a building so it's an occupied cell but this is a street so it's a free cell?

The program should take a map in XML file for example and automatically output the OGM.

Comment: No, it will most likely not be enough for robot localization. There are a lot of things changing all the time in the real world, and they will not be visible in the map. The robot's localization is likely to fail if you use outdated data from the map.

Comment: @mikkola ,, Thank you for replying,, I would just like to know if there is a way that I could extract the data I need from the map,, I just need to know if this approach is possible,, thank you

Comment: I do not know of existing software to do this. but you could do it yourself using image processing. Heres a high level process: Divide the visual map into small units (for example a pixel == 1 meter) and look at the color of each pixel. OpenStreetMap has a few colors for roads and highways (white, yellow, orange, red) and decide if the current pixel is a street color. You could give this a low value. and other colors a high occupancy value. As mikkola said, it won't be enough on its own. But, it could be a starting point and the bot can update the occupancy grid using sensor readings